# Почему не работает svg?

Tags: svg

Подскажите, что не так. Код не мой, был в открытом доступе, я его применила у себя. Зашла по прошествии года и увидела не работающий код. Нашла, что изменилась версия, но так и не разобралась.
Подскажите, что поменять. Почитала, что textLength уже не работает, заменила его, но это не решило проблему.
[Ссылка на код](https://codepen.io/Adeoladev/pen/QWpQmwM)

```css
body { 
  margin: 0;
  background: #000;
  text-align: center;
}
svg { width: 20%; }
rect { fill: #FE0304; }
text { 
  font-size: 2.4rem;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100; 
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 38px;
    fill: white;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
  <defs>
    <path d="M50,250c0-110.5,89.5-200,200-200s200,89.5,200,200s-89.5,200-200,200S50,360.5,50,250" id="textcircle">
      <animateTransform attributeName="transform" begin="0s" dur="30s" type="rotate" from="0 250 250" to="360 250 250" repeatCount="indefinite" />
    </path>
  </defs>
  <text dy="80" textLength="50">
    <textPath xlink:href="#textcircle"> &nbsp; Alexxandria Forsque</textPath>
  </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: выставили textlength, поле сжалось все буквы друг на друге. Что на что вы заменили - не ясно

Comment: Код не мой и в таком виде он раньше работал. Я попробовала убрать textLength, буквы стали на место, но должна быть анимация по кругу

Comment: по вашей ссылке на кодпен текст летает по кругу, по крайней мере в ФФ

Comment: В хроме тоже летает надпись нормально, если textLength убрать

Comment: А что тогда может быть, в чем проблема? У меня хром

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам только саму анимацию, то есть animateTransform убрать из defs и поместить не посредственно в код текста и в этом случае все начинает крутиться

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="180 177 145 145" width="200">
  <defs>
    <path d="M50,250 c0-110.5,89.5-200,200-200s200,89.5,200,200s-89.5,200-200,200S50,360.5,50,250z" id="path">

    </path>
  </defs>
  <text dy="140" textLength="1200" font-weight="bold">
    <textPath href="#path"> &nbsp; Alexxandria &nbsp; Forsque</textPath>
    <animateTransform begin="0s" attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="rotate" from="0 250 250" to="360 250 250" dur="10s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Спасибо, да , заработало.

Comment: спасибо, разбираюсь, где у меня ошибка. Не могу добавить голос, только зарегистрировалась, поэтому спасибо

Comment: @Vita Теперь вы можете добавить голос :)